# Choppy or jerky video playback (even in glxgears) on 18.04

Tags: video, intel-graphics, thinkpad, playback

On my Lenovo Thinkpad T460s with Intel HD Graphics 520 I get choppy video playback in browsers, media-players and even glxgears. There's sudden stops or jerks every 1 second or so without continuously. I had no such problems on 16.04 and KDE Neon (also 16.04 based). I see there are many questions about choppy video playback but no solutions with regards to my hardware unless I am missing something. Any idea what I can do to troubleshoot and if possible solve it.